# Converting email metadata RFC 5322 dates to Org mode dates in doom emacs

Tags: date, vim, emacs, vi

I have about 200 old emails, as *.eml files, that I want to concatenate into one *.org file so that I can use the information in Org mode. Each file has the string "Date: " followed by a timestamp in the RFC 5322 date format, i.e.

`Date: Tue, 23 Apr 2019 13:31:18 -0400`

I know the UNIX `date` command can convert the date part of that string to RFC 3339 date format, i.e. the command:

`date --rfc-3339='ns' --date='Tue, 23 Apr 2019 13:31:18 -0400'`

would give the result:

`2019-04-23 13:31:18.000000000-04:00`

I guess I could do all the conversion with awk in one go, but my awk is rusty, and I've been having trouble getting it right.

I'd really like to convert all of these dates to Org mode dates with one command, either using a vi command or a doom emacs command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could build up a regular expression for use with `M-x query-replace-regexp` which invokes a shell command to use the date command you mention above.  The trick is the `\,` replacement option which allows you to execute any Emacs LISP code, as described in the Regexp Replacement section of the Emacs info manual.